# Why is useRef initialized with null in React examples?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) and ~all examples I saw `useRef` is used like this:

```js
const ref = useRef(null);
```

I found that it works without passing any arguments. What's the purpose of explicitly passing `null`?

Answer (score -2):

The `useRef` Hook is a function that returns a mutable `ref` object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

However, the `ref` is not set till the function returns and the content is rendered.

So the ref are declare as `null` because no component is loaded or render on screen and declaring value before render would error.

Comment: "declaring value before render would error" This doesn't make sense to me. What's wrong with `undefined` before render?

Comment: for example i am creating new ```ref``` for my ```div``` element.   So first of all when page loads, ```render``` method would be called at last. so before ```render``` method is called, the ```ref``` initialization would take place and if you have passed the reference of theat ```div``` to ```ref```, then it would be wrong because the ```div``` is not been render on screen yet and you are referring it.

Comment: I understand how that works, I don't get the upside of using `null` explicitly. Why not just leave it undefined? Either way you should check if the ref is set before using it: `if (ref.current !== null) {...}`.